# Can't get background image to show in div?

Tags: css, html, background

AS the subject outlines, the background div will not show, I thought you needed to define the width and height, but this doesnt work, ive checked the names and filepaths and these all seem ok.

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/invoicestyle.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="header">
    <div id="logo"><img src="images/ATT3006209.jpg" /></div>
    <div id="card"><img src="images/ATT3006207.jpg" /><br /><img src="images/ATT3006208.jpg" /></div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <div id="tagline"><p>Tagline goes here</p></div>
    </div>

    <div id="bar">
        <div id="left"></div>
        <div id="middle"></div>
        <div id="right"></div>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>

</div>
</body>
```

```css
body{
background:#FFF;
font-family:Arial;
font-size:12px;
}

.clear{
clear:both;
}
#wrapper{
width:1000px;
margin:auto;
}
#logo{
float:left;
}
#card{
float:right;
}
#card img{
padding-bottom:5px;
}

#bar{overflow: hidden;}
#left{
background: url("images/left.jpg") no-repeat;
width:10px;
height:50px;
float:left;
display: block
}
#middle{
background: url("images/mid.jpg") repeat-x; 
width:980px;
height:50px;
float:left;
display: block
}
#right{
background: url("images/right.jpg") no-repeat;
width:10px;
height:50px;
float:right;
display: block
}
```

Comment: You sure you mean `images/` and not `../images/`?

Comment: Are you using an external css file? can you post your folders structure?

Comment: doesnt make a difference

Comment: rest of the css is fine and is seen by the html file

Comment: did you try adding `display: block` to those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to add

`#bar{overflow: hidden;}`

I am not sure if your css for `.clear` is correct because you did not paste it, it might be the case it is not. Please let me know whether the problem still exists.

Comment: seems like it should do the trick. I would have tried overflow: hidden anyway, though I am not so sure anymore if it will help. Do you have any link where I can debug it with firebug? As a debug process, try to change image to background: pink; background: blue; etc , if it will work then there is something wrong with images. In such case I would ensure that image's size is not greater then declared width and height in div.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot set the `background-repeat` property inside the `background-image` one. Either make that `background` on its own, or move the `repeat` stuff onto its own `background-repeat` property, as it should be.

Comment: first was an old version, changed to jsut using background: url () now. see edited OP

Comment: Try also adding quotes around the image urls (not required, but may be confusing the browser)

Answer (score 0):

```
#bar
{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
}
```

now i use your code in my project. and i add this code its working in my project.

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

http://jsfiddle.net/9ygJG/

```
#bar {
background: orange;
width: 100%;
height: 10em;  
}

#left{
width:10px;
height:50px;
float:left;
background-color: black;
background-image: url(images/left.jpg) no-repeat;
}
#middle{
width:980px;
height:50px;
float:left;
background-color: blue;
background-image: url(images/mid.jpg) repeat-x; 

}
#right{
width:10px;
height:50px;
float:right;
background-color: black;
background-image: url(images/right.jpg) no-repeat; 
}​
```

Comment: Obviously I added background-color because you're using relative urls in your own project.